# Math notation formatting in comments is lost when the comments are expanded

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, mathjax

From the comments on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3444/intuition-for-the-definition-of-the-gamma-function).

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Browser is FF 3.6.6 on WinXP. I'm going to update to 3.6.10 now to see if it fixes the problem. Edit: No, that didn't fix it. This is probably a JavaScript bug.

Comment: +1, but shouldn't this be asked at meta.math since TeX is not a general SE feature atm?

Comment: @Tobias: Good point. Hmmm... Even though it's not a general feature, it *could* be implemented on multiple SE sites, or be a bug with the engine. In either of those cases, the question should belong here, so I think this is okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be fixed now.